# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined while saving contact in IONIC 4

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, contacts

I want to save the contact to my phone book.
I followed the instructions at https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts

**detail.html**

```
<div class="call">
     <ion-buttons slot="primary">
         <ion-button size="small" (click)="save(memberData.contact_no,memberData.fname,memberData.lname)">
              Save Contact
              <ion-icon slot="end" name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
         </ion-button>
     </ion-buttons>
</div>
```

**detail.ts**

```
import { Contacts, Contact, ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts/ngx';

constructor(private contacts: Contacts) { }

save(number: string, firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    // alert(number + " " + firstName + " " + lastName);

    let contact: Contact = this.contacts.create();

    contact.name = new ContactName(null, firstName, lastName);
    contact.phoneNumbers = [new ContactField('mobile', number)];
    contact.save()
    .then(() => console.log('Contact saved!', contact),
      (error: any) => console.error('Error saving contact.', error))
    .catch(err => console.log('Catch : Error saving contact', err));
  }
```

**Error**

> common.js:290 Native: tried calling Contacts.create, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>
> MemberDetailPage.html:17 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

[image]

Comment: Have you added `cordova-plugin-contacts` plugin?

Comment: Yes. I added ````ionic cordova plugin add call-number

npm install @ionic-native/call-number 
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts

npm install @ionic-native/contacts````  plugins

Comment: on which device are you trying to save??

Comment: On MI note 4. @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: Are you testing this directly on your Note 4 or in a simulator? Based on the first error ("Cordova is not available"), it seems like the device is not Cordova compatibe.

Comment: You must test in either a device emulator or an actual hardware to use cordova plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error while testing inside the browser. Try launching an android studio version of your app for Android or inside Xcode for iOS to see if the plugin works.

If you're trying to test cordova plugins in the browser alone maybe this could help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/simulate-in-browser?view=toolsforcordova-2017.

In general always use a real device or an emulator for testing native capabilities.